# UWP XAML making ListView only as long as its children

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I'm creating a ListView with a variable number of children, but I know that number of children will always fit on the page without scrolling.

I need the height of the ListView to only extend as long as the children, not all the way to the bottom of the container (a Grid, in this case).

In other words, if I define a border around the ListView, I'd like the outer border of the ListView to have no space between the bottom border and the bottom child.  How can I achieve this?  Every approach I've tried so far leaves me with a large space between the last child and the bottom border of the ListView if I only have a few child ListViewItems.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in a way that will look seamless if I change the size of the screen by dragging the corner of the window to a different size (that's a nice to have, not a requirement).

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Contacts}" />
```

As you can see, the list can be any length, depending on the length of Contacts, so I can't just set the size of the containing grid to be a certain height, and I can't set the height of the ListView itself to a fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you need to custom `ListView` and calculate all item's height then make ListView's height same as all items height summation. For more please refer the following code.

```
public sealed class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomListView);
        this.Loaded += CustomListView_Loaded;
    }

    private void CustomListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listItem = this.Items[0];
        var listItemContainer = this.ContainerFromItem(listItem) as ListViewItem;
        var height = listItemContainer.ActualHeight;
        var marginTop = listItemContainer.Margin.Top;
        var rowHeight = marginTop + height;
        var sum = this.Items.Count * rowHeight;
        this.Height = sum;
    }   
}
```